# Convert Excel's "41014" date to actual date in PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, excel

I'm writing something in PHP/Jquery that allows the user to upload an Excel spreadsheet from Excel.  It then takes the data in that spreadsheet and assigns the values from each cell into a variable, but for some reason, I'm having a hard time with dates.  Any date in Excel comes in as a number, like `41014`, instead of `04/15/2012` (as if I were to format in Excel as `text`).

How do I convert this to a YYYY-MM-DD format so it fits in with the rest of the mySQL database I'm working with?  I can do it either in PHP or Jquery, but doing it in jQuery seems easier to me.

**Excel's Cell**

```
04/15/2012
```

**PHP's `echo json_encode($var);`**

```
`{dateReceived: 41014}`
```

**jQuery's `console.log(dateReceived);`**

```
41014
```

## Update

I couldn't actually get either of the answers provided here to work - I thought the php answer worked initially, but for some reason I couldn't get it to output what I needed, but I found another simple formula that I put into a function.  In case anyone else is looking for an answer to a similar question, here's what I did:, (where $dateValue is the Excel Date `41014` etc...)

```
function convertDate($dateValue) {    

  $unixDate = ($dateValue - 25569) * 86400;
  return gmdate("Y-m-d", $unixDate);
  'where Y is YYYY, m is MM, and d is DD

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken directly from the PHPExcel Date handling code:

```
public static function ExcelToPHP($dateValue = 0) {
    if (self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900) {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 25569;
        //    Adjust for the spurious 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($dateValue < 60) {
            --$myExcelBaseDate;
        }
    } else {
        $myExcelBaseDate = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($dateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $dateValue - $myExcelBaseDate;
        $returnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($returnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($returnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $returnValue = (integer) $returnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($dateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($dateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($dateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $returnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    // Return
    return $returnValue;
}    //    function ExcelToPHP()
```

Set self::$ExcelBaseDate == self::CALENDAR_WINDOWS_1900 as necessary to indicate the Excel base calendar that you're using: Windows 1900 or Mac 1904... most likely 1900

and if you want a PHP DateTime object instead:

```
public static function ExcelToPHPObject($dateValue = 0) {
    $dateTime = self::ExcelToPHP($dateValue);
    $days = floor($dateTime / 86400);
    $time = round((($dateTime / 86400) - $days) * 86400);
    $hours = round($time / 3600);
    $minutes = round($time / 60) - ($hours * 60);
    $seconds = round($time) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);

    $dateObj = date_create('1-Jan-1970+'.$days.' days');
    $dateObj->setTime($hours,$minutes,$seconds);

    return $dateObj;
}    //    function ExcelToPHPObject()
```

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't get this to work....... with a bit more searching, I found a simple formula that I wrote into a function.  In the event anyone else reads this thread looking for an answer, I've updated my original question with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: It's part of a class, you did wrap those two method up inside a class didn't you? Or call them statically?

Comment: I didn't.  I don't know what php classes are - I've never used one, which might explain why this didn't work :)

Comment: wow, quite a read!  Thank you for linking it... lots of good stuff in here!

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer JavaScript, I have found the following formula on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/christopherscott/2782634):

```
new Date((excelDate - (25567 + 2))*86400*1000)
```

Works for your given date. Maybe you can give it a try whether it returns the correct date for other values.

Answer (score 0):

Using what @QueryLars suggested this is the simplest working solution in PHP:

```
$excelDate = 43407; //2018-11-03
$miliseconds = ($excelDate - (25567 + 2)) * 86400 * 1000;
$seconds = $miliseconds / 1000;
echo date("Y-m-d", $seconds); //2018-11-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Those 5 digit Numbers I think are dates in Julian format, That must be the numerical universal way of expressing date and Time,

For Eg Jul. number `36309` => `1999-05-29` (common Database date format)
number `44225.403368056` => `2021-01-29 09:40:51` (For date-time, the fractions represent time)

To do this conversion, using language php here, but it can be changed to any language of preference with use of similar built in functions

```php
function correctDateTime($dateTime)
{
    # integer digits for Julian date
    $julDate = floor($dateTime);
    # The fractional digits for Julian Time
    $julTime = $dateTime - $julDate;
    # Converts to Timestamp
    $timeStamp = ($julDate > 0) ? ($julDate - 25569) * 86400 + $julTime * 86400 : $julTime * 86400;

   # php date function to convert local time
    return [
        "Date-Time"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timeStamp),
        "Date"=>date("Y-m-d", $timeStamp),
        "Time"=>date("H:i:s", $timeStamp)
    ];
}

$formattedValue = correctDateTime("44225.403368056");

echo $formattedValue["Date-Time"] . "\n";   // 2021-01-29 09:40:51
echo $formattedValue["Date"] . "\n";   // 2021-01-29
echo $formattedValue["Time"] . "\n";   // 09:40:51
```