# PHPExcel converting dates to store in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

While importing dates from excel using PHPExcel imported value is in integer format. so date '02-11-2090' (d-m-Y) format is uploaded as integer 69704.

I am using following function to convert the integer into MySQL accepted date format: Reference ([Convert Excel's "41014" date to actual date in PHP or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305688/convert-excels-41014-date-to-actual-date-in-php-or-javascript))

```
function convertDate($dateValue) {    

  $unixDate = ($dateValue - 25569) * 86400;
  return gmdate("Y-m-d", $unixDate);

}
```

When I call the function using 69704 as the dateValue it returns '1954-09-26' as the date instead of '02-11-2090'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running on a 32-bit version of PHP, which has a date range of between 1901-12-13 and 2038-01-19.... if you need to use dates outside of this range, then switch to using a 64-bit version of PHP.